# radio button value gets change by changing variable name in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to get value of radio button .  This HTML

```
  <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let option of mainOption?.options[0]?.suboptions, let i = index " style="padding: 0;width: 100%;">
              <div class="row" style="margin: 0;">
                  
                <div class="changed p-0" style="width: 15px;place-self: center;">
                  
                  <input type="radio" class="float-right form-check-input position-static"
                    name="{{option.extra_option_id}}" [value]='option' [(ngModel)]="option[i]"
                    (ngModelChange)='changeEventInRadioButton($event)' style="margin: 0;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-8 p-2">
                  <div class="float-left">
                    <span class="inputdisplay">{{ option.name }}</span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="inputdisplay1" style="font-size: 14px;">+ {{ option.price | currency }}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Here are two variable with same name `option` one is `object` other is an `array` which is global

No I am trying to get value of this radio button it works fine when name is same for both variables

which is this object

```
{
    "id": 267,
    "suboptions": [
        {
            "id": 765,
            "name": "Fanta",
            "price": 2,
            "position": "whole",
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

This object is created inside `changeEventInRadioButton` function

```
  changeEventInRadioButton(val) {
    console.log('gh',val);
    console.log('Array',this.option)
   // this.option = [];
    let suboptions = [
      {
        "id": val.id,
        "name": val.name,
        "price": val.price,
        "position": "whole",
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ];
    let data = {
        "id": val.extra_option_id,
        "suboptions": suboptions
        };
    
    let obj = this.option.some(obj => obj.id == data.id);
     console.log('id',obj,'data',data.id)
    if(obj){
      console.log('cc',obj)
      let objIndex = this.option.findIndex((obj => obj.id == data.id));
      this.option[objIndex].suboptions = suboptions;
    }else{
      this.option.push(data);
    }
    console.log("Option Value ", this.option);

  }
```

but when i change the name of `object` variable then it gives me this this value for `this.option`

```
[
    {
        "id": 749,
        "extra_option_id": 262,
        "name": "Small",
        "price": 1,
        "image": null,
        "sku": null,
        "rank": 1,
        "description": null,
        "max": 1,
        "half_price": null,
        "enabled": true,
        "created_at": "2021-02-10 16:54:08",
        "updated_at": "2021-02-19 05:43:45",
        "deleted_at": null
    },
    {
        "id": 262,
        "suboptions": [
            {
                "id": 749,
                "name": "Small",
                "price": 1,
                "position": "whole",
                "quantity": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

you see one additional object is added at index 0

Why is this happpening?

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz link for that problem? Then it will be easy to solve your problem. Best wishes :-)

Answer (score 2):

To use object array with radio buttons you can use the code below =>
**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  favoriteSeason1: string;
  tests: Test[] = [{name:'sjn',id:1},{name:'sjnf',id:2},{name:'ilysna',id:3}];
}
export class Test{
 name:string ;
 id:number;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div *ngFor="let tt of tests; let i = index">
  <input id="tt.name{{i}}" name="seasons" type="radio"
    [value]="tt.name" [(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason1" />
  <label for="">{{tt.name}}</label>
</div>
```

You can check the [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-model-and-radio-buttons-qdmn8a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)